# Estimating covariances of observed variables with lavaan

Tags: r, covariance

I am puzzled with the behavior of R's `lavaan` package. I am trying to estimate the variances and covariances of two observed variables.

Here is the data:

```
bd <- data.frame(
          Group = c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
                 3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,2L,
                 2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
                 2L),
          HIP_D = c(2763,3241.5,2740.5,3318,3501,3634.5,
                 4324.5,2970,3168,3307.5,3145.5,3639,3325.5,3295.5,3066,
                 3711,2488.5,3333,3138,2752.5,3096,2785.5,3204,3781.5,
                 3207,2742,3082.5,2665.5,2737.5,2664,2743.5,2695.5,3244.5,
                 3024,2422.5,1605,2943,2314.5,2971.5,3187,2673,3024,
                 2992.5),
          HIP_E = c(2505,3292.5,2646.7,3457.5,3505.5,
                 3628.5,4152,2686.5,2943,2913,3283.5,3546,3172.5,3090,3211.5,
                 3880.5,1725,3147,3055.5,2776.5,2904,2785.5,3159,
                 3418.5,3240,2334,2634,2370,2736,2503.5,2325,2409,3057,
                 2692.5,2443.5,1645.5,2922,1818,2679,2742,2465.5,2911.5,
                 2890.5)
)
```

My code is as follows:

```
modVL <- '
HIP_D ~~ HIP_D
HIP_E ~~ HIP_E
HIP_D ~~ HIP_E
'
library(lavaan)
fitVL <- sem(modVL, data=bd, likelihood = "wishart",  orthogonal = FALSE)
summary(fitVL, standardize=T)
```

And the output is:

```
lavaan 0.6-7 ended normally after 8 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of free parameters                          3
                                                      
  Number of observations                            43
                                                      
Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                                81.564
  Degrees of freedom                                 0

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                             Standard
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured

Covariances:
                   Estimate    Std.Err   z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv    Std.all
  HIP_D ~~                                                                   
    HIP_E               0.000 36570.317    0.000    1.000      0.000    0.000

Variances:
                   Estimate    Std.Err   z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv    Std.all
    HIP_D          203990.618 44514.402    4.583    0.000 203990.618    1.000
    HIP_E          275357.264 60087.881    4.583    0.000 275357.264    1.000
```

Now, the two variables (HIP_D and HIP_E) are very strongly correlated:

```
correlation::correlation(bd)

Parameter1 | Parameter2 |    r |       95% CI |     t | df |      p |  Method | n_Obs
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HIP_D      |      HIP_E | 0.93 | [0.87, 0.96] | 15.65 | 41 | < .001 | Pearson |    43
```

So, there's no way the covariance could be zero!... I am puzzled with how lavaan is forcing the covariance to zero?

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, it's a scaling problem. Covariances estimates are too large. Dividing the variables by 10 gives results for covariance (re-scaled).